# how to change leaflet attribution

Tags: javascript, angularjs, leaflet

I'm using Leaflet with [Esri.WorldShadedRelief](https://leaflet-extras.github.io/leaflet-providers/preview/#filter=Esri.WorldShadedRelief). 
As far as I understand I need to set the Leaflet attribution as follows:
'Tiles © Esri — Source: Esri'
How ever when I try to set it up, it doesn't change.
I'm using **AngularJS**.

My Leaflet defaults:

```
defaults: {
    keyboard: false,
    dragging: false,
    worldCopyJump: false,
    doubleClickZoom: false,
    scrollWheelZoom: false,
    tap: false,
    touchZoom: false,
    zoomControl: false,
    zoomsliderControl: false,
    zoomControlPosition: 'topleft',
    attributionControl: true,
    attribution: 'Tiles &copy; Esri &mdash; Source: Esri',
    controls: {
        layers: {
            visible: true,
            position: 'topright',
            collapsed: true,
        },
    }
},
tiles: {
    url: 'https://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Shaded_Relief/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `addAttribution` to the map object via `attributionControl`:

`map.attributionControl.addAttribution('Tiles &copy; Esri &mdash; Source: Esri');`

This will change it globally and not for a specific layer.

Comment: I'm using Angularjs, I've no reference to the map. I tried to get a reference to the map with no success.