# Change default attribution text location in Contextily

Tags: python, contextily

Using this code:

```
import contextily as ctx
from shapely.geometry import box
import geopandas as gpd

minx, miny = 1.612359e+06, 0.950860e+07
maxx, maxy = 4.320331e+06, 1.007808e+07
rectangle = box(minx, miny, maxx, maxy)
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
    index=['Amazon'],
    geometry=[rectangle],
    crs='EPSG:5641')

dy = 10e4
ax = gdf.plot(figsize=(8,3), facecolor='none', edgecolor='lime')
ax.set_ylim(miny-dy, maxy+dy)
ctx.add_basemap(ax, crs=gdf.crs.to_string())
```

To get this plot:

[image]

I know [it's possible](https://contextily.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference.html#plotting-basemaps) to change the size of the attribution text in `contextily`, and even to not plot it, but is there a way to change its location, e.g. to write it on the right or at the top?

Similar to how to [change leaflet attribution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51997891/774575), but for `contextily`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you can't define the attribution in the add_basemap function, and while contextily does provide a more adaptable [add_attribution](https://contextily.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference.html#contextily.add_attribution) function, that doesn't allow you to specify the text position. There is another way though: manipulate the matplotlib text object generated by add_basemap:

```
txt = ax.texts[-1]
txt.set_position([0.99,0.98])
txt.set_ha('right')
txt.set_va('top')
```

Example output below. Best do this immediately after the add_basemap call to be sure you don't pick up any other text object.

[image: The original image but with attribution position in top right using the code above.]